# Script mysql table export | It only exports 1 table per time

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

1. I'm creating an script for optimize time in my development
   environment.
2. I create this one for export tables,it works very well, but it is
   limited.

> How can I improve this script to export 1 or more tables at the
>   sametime? Could be 2 tables or 30 tables, I don't wanna add one
>   **read** and one **variable** to evrey and each input for the table...

```
base_dados_table () {
            echo 'Nome da BD:'
                read db_name
                    echo 'Nome da Tabela:'
                read table_name
                    echo 'Dump name'
                read dump_name
                        clear
    }

    base_dados_table
        mysqldump -u$login -p$password "${db_name}.${table_name}" > "${dump_name}_table.sql"
            ls -lah | grep -i "${dp_name}.sql"
        echo 'obrigado !'
```

Comment: mysqldump exports databases and tables. so if you want to export a complete database dont use the table name, if you want to import many tables add also multiple "${db_name}.${table_name}" with different names

Comment: Yes, this is the obvious way, for example I want to make and if statement for add or not more tables, how can I insert in the mysqldump line ?

Comment: I want to give an option of how many tables the user wants to import.

Comment: you must have a list of of names and then you loop and build a string variable, is one possibility. Simpy start something and see it it fits and if not ask.

Comment: I manage to do with the following script:

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
GIT_MYSQL=/home/zuka/tables
for T in `mysql -uuser -ppasword -N -B -e 'show tables from database'`;
do
    echo "Backing up $T"
    mysqldump --skip-comments --compact -uuser -ppassword database $T > $GIT_MYSQL/$T.sql
done;
```

This solved my issue.